# How to conveniently align numbers centrally in C++ cout

Tags: c++

I have the following matrix stored in a int[][] in c++ (sorry that I did not put all the commas in):

```
int[8][]a={
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 
  28   29   30   31   32   33   34    9 
  27   48   49   50   51   52   35   10 
  26   47   60   61   62   53   36   11 
  25   46   59   64   63   54   37   12 
  24   45   58   57   56   55   38   13 
  23   44   43   42   41   40   39   14 
  22   21   20   19   18   17   16   15};
```

And I need to print it out with single digits align nicely with the rest. How to do this conveniently? I've already used `setw`, but it seems it only causes the output to be right-justified.

Thank you.

**Edit**

Maybe I did not say this clearly. Sorry about that. I want the output to be something like:

```
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 
  228  129  130  131   32   33   34    9
```

Assuming I have more digits in the numbers.

Comment: If "centrally" means you want whitespace on the number's right, consider putting this in front (left) - then setw will do the job nicely.

Comment: Every time I try and do this the C++ way, I give up after a while and just hack it in with `printf` in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 8):

You want to #include iomanip, and use std::setw, and std::right (or one of the other alignments mentioned by Dietmar Kühl). Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int numbers[4][4] = {
        {1, 10, 5, 6},
        {536, 5769, 342, 112},
        {2,43,43,6},
        {2,2,2,3}};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << std::right << std::setw(7) << numbers[i][j];
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, I'm printing numbers right aligned with a column width of 7, the resultant output is as follows:

```
      1     10      5      6
    536   5769    342    112
      2     43     43      6
      2      2      2      3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can choose where the padding should go:

- `out << std::left` will cause the output to be left justified
- `out << std::right` will cause the output to be right justified
- `out << std::internal` will left justify any sign and right justify the number
- `out << std::showpos` will display both a positive and a negative sign (in case you want to see the effect of `std::internal`

Initially the stream is set up to do left justification (although I strangle don't see the corresponding definition in the standard).

Answer (score 0):

To print the numbers centered in a field:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


// Print num centered in width columns
void centerint(int num, int width)
{
  stringstream ss;
  ss << num;
  string str = ss.str();
  int pad = (width - str.size())/2;
  for(int i=0; i<pad; i++)
    cout << " ";
  cout << str << endl;
}

int main()
{
  // lets try a few
  centerint(  1,  9);
  centerint(-238, 9);
  centerint( 16,  9);
}
```

This prints:

```
    1
  -238
   16
```